# Как создать предпросмотр в Telegram для файла любого размера?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

У меня бот отправлен ссылку на прямое скачивание .mp4 с моего сервера.
Если видео до 30 секунд, то в телеграм появляется предпросмотр, где его можно скачать и посмотреть.
Но если видео длинное, предпросмотра нет.
Как сделать что бы он был всегда, даже если видео больше чем 5-10 минут.

Comment: предпросмотр Вы имеете в виду картинка? если да то извлекайте либо кадр либо сетку кадров ffmpeg например и прикладывайте к посту

Comment: Точно не уверен, но попробую предположить, что телеграм хочет, чтобы moov atom в mp4-файле находился в начале файла. Попробуйте переместить его с помощью qt-faststart или через ffmpeg с опцией "-movflags faststart", вдруг это что-то изменит